# Python: how set value of subclassed int with __setitem__

Tags: python, immutability, subclassing

I'am struggling with the implementation of **setitem** on a subclassed int class.

I want to perform operations on bit slices of that int (limited to 32bit).
I know there is a 'BitVector' class available but this doesn't work as one would expect.
For example:

```
from BitVector import BitVector
foo = BitVector(intVal = 0x87654321)
print(f'[0:3] expected value = 0x1 returned value = {hex(int(foo[0:3]))}')
print(f'[4:7] expected value = 0x2 returned value = {hex(int(foo[4:7]))}')
print(f'[24:31] expected value = 0x87 returned value = {hex(int(foo[24:31]))}')
```

Output is:

```
[0:3] expected value = 0x1 returned value = 0x4
[4:7] expected value = 0x2 returned value = 0x3
[24:31] expected value = 0x87 returned value = 0x10
```

The problem with BitVector is that the bit order is reversed (LSB is left, MSB is right) and also the end bit is not included in the slice ([0:3] returns three bits instead of four bits).

So I decided to create my own class for that kind of operations.
(I reversed the order of start and end so that I would write [3:0] instead of [0:3] which is the more common notation)
The **getitem** works as expected but I can't set the new value using **setitem**.

```
class bitfield(int):
def __str__(self):
    return "%d" % int(self)

def __repr__(self):
    return "bitfield(%d)" % int(self)

def __getitem__(self, sliceobj):
    if not isinstance( sliceobj, slice ): return (self&(1<<sliceobj))>>sliceobj
    if(sliceobj.start < sliceobj.stop): raise ValueError( "slice error: start must be >= end" )
    if(sliceobj.start > 31): raise ValueError( "slice error: start > 31" )
    if(sliceobj.stop   > 31): raise ValueError( "slice error: end > 31" )
    start = sliceobj.start
    stop   = sliceobj.stop
    mask = (1<<((start+1) - stop))-1
    val = self & ( mask << stop)
    val = val>>stop
    return val
def __new__(cls, value):
    return int.__new__(bitfield, value)
def __setitem__(self, sliceobj, item):
    self.__int__ = 0x1234
    self = 0x1234
    #self.__int__ = int.__new__(bitfield, 0x1234)
    self = int.__new__(bitfield, 0x1234)
    self = self.__new__(bitfield, 0x1234)


# test __getitem__ 
a = bitfield(0xB2)
print(f'       {bin(a)}'     )
print(f'[0]    {bin(a[0  ])}')
print(f'[1]    {bin(a[1  ])}')
print(f'[1:0]  {bin(a[1:0])}')
print(f'[4:0]  {bin(a[4:0])}')
print(f'[7:1]  {bin(a[7:1])}')
print(f'[8:0]  {bin(a[8:0])}')
a = bitfield(0xbefa55aa)
print(f'       {hex(a)}'       )
print(f'[7:0]  {hex(a[ 7:0] )}')
print(f'[15:8] {hex(a[15:8] )}')
print(f'[23:16]{hex(a[23:16])}')
print(f'[31:24]{hex(a[31:24])}')

# test __setitem__
a = bitfield(0)
a[1] = 1
print(hex(a))
```

Output is:

```
       0b10110010
[0]    0b0
[1]    0b1
[1:0]  0b10
[4:0]  0b10010
[7:1]  0b1011001
[8:0]  0b10110010
       0xbefa55aa
[7:0]  0xaa
[15:8] 0x55
[23:16]0xfa
[31:24]0xbe
       0b0   <-- expected 0x1234 !!!
```

Can some give me a hint how to set a new value?

Answer (score 0):

> Can some give me a hint how to set a new value?

Don't inherit from int. Integers are immutable, you can't update their value in-place.

> The problem with BitVector is that the bit order is reversed (LSB is left, MSB is right) and also the end bit is not included in the slice ([0:3] returns three bits instead of four bits).

So what you're saying is that bitvector behaves like a [`sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) of bits? instead of behaving like essentially nothing else in the language?

Comment: Is it possible to make the class be interpretable as integer if it don't inherit from integer? I am getting following error when trying to print the value: `TypeError: 'bitfield' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. Well the fact that [0:1] is the same as [0] in python is a bit quirky and counterintuitive, don't you think?

Comment: "Is it possible to make the class be interpretable as integer if it don't inherit from integer?" it's not possible to make it fully interchangeable with an integer, though it's possible to make it contextually convertible to an integer using `__int__` and `__index__`.

Comment: "Well the fact that [0:1] is the same as [0] in python is a bit quirky and counterintuitive, don't you think?" That's not generally true, therefore not a fact, so no (in the builtins I think it only happens with `str` which is somewhat special and not in a good way)

Comment: "I am getting following error when trying to print the value: `TypeError: 'bitfield' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.`" The `%d` formatter strictly requires an integer. Don't use that if your type is not an actual integer.